# Example for a polynomially compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, examples-counterexamples, normed-spaces, compact-operators

I understand to say that a bounded linear operator $T$ is called "polynomially compact" if there is a nonzero polynomial $p$ such that $p(T)$ is compact.

Can anyone help me with examples of polynomially compact operators?

Comment: Where have you read this notion? Can you add a reference.

Comment: Peter Rosenthal Heydar Radjavi. Invariant Subspaces, Heidelberg, 1973. 17 volume 1. Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg, 1973.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every compact operator is polynomially compact.

**Edit.** If you want to have a non-trivial example take any bounded non-compact operator $T$ such that $T^2$ is compact (see e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290479/is-there-an-example-of-a-non-compact-operator-whose-square-is-compact)). Then one can take $p(x) = x^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However I've read a statement saying that "every polynomially compact operator is compact but the converse does not holds." How do I link this to your response

Comment: @MPHIRI take $p(x)=x$.

Answer (score 2):

I think a natural example is that of nilpotent operators. Ie: operators such that $T^n = 0$, for large $n$. You can easily construct non-compact nilpotent operators. Take the $2\times2$-matrix $A = e_{2 1}$. $T = A^{\oplus \infty}$ (an infinite direct sum of $A$-blocks) is nilpotent but not compact.